# iphone subview not response click event

Tags: iphone, events, click, subview

What I did :

```
self.blsController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextPage"];
    self.blsController.view.frame= CGRectMake(self.blsController.view.frame.size.width , 0, self.blsController.view.frame.size.width, self.blsController.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.blsController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.blsController.view ];
```

and I moved the parent view to show the subview,

```
self.view.center = pollPoint;
```

but the subview is not responding to click event

I tried :

> 1. [self.blsController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
> 2. add touchesEnded in subview controller however they don't work, please tell me why and how to do with this.

thx

Comment: try to set cancelsTouchesInView to NO

Answer (score 0):

You should not move the parent view itself then you wont be able to get touch to any of its subview too buddy. if the user will tap on the screen and main view is out of screen then subviews also wont receive the touch.

Comment: I want to show two views in the screen at the same time, and both views can receive the touch events.if my way not works please tell me how to do with this thank you